# HTML Form method="post"

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to understand an existing piece of software, and have come accross the following:

```
<form name="AppForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" onsubmit="return fnPreSubmit()">

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Apply now"/>

</form>
```

On the screen there is a button with the text "Apply Now", and From what I understand, the `input`tags of the HTML create this button.

I am trying to understand what happens in the code when the button is pressed.

Previously, when I have used forms, `action` has had a value, for example a page name, so I could work out where the code was going.

In this case, `action` does not have a value. From searching on the internet, it seems this means the form is being submitted to the same page.

My question is, how can I tell where on the page the code is being submitted to? Or, to put it another way, how can I work out what is going on with the code after the button has been pressed?

Is it the case that the page is reloaded again, and all the data that has been filled out in the form is posted to the page and the page loads with that data already loaded?

Here is the JS method fnPreSubmit and any related methods. It seems to me these validate the form before it posts back to the same page?

```
    function fnPreSubmit()
    {
        var oFrm = document.forms['AppForm'];

        // First set any disable inputs back to enabled so that the value gets sent
        for (var ii = 0; ii < arrROC.length; ii++)
        {
            var oReadOnlyInput = oFrm[arrROC[ii][0]];
            if (oReadOnlyInput.disabled)
            {
                oReadOnlyInput.disabled = false;
            }
        }

        // Sort out the date fields
        fnProcessDateFields(oFrm);

        dataLayer.push({'event': 'ApplicationSubmit'});

        return true;
    }

    function fnProcessDateFields(pFrm)
    {
        var sName = "";

        if (pFrm['datefield'] != undefined)
        {
            for (var ii = 0; ii < pFrm['datefield'].length; ii++)
            {
                sName = pFrm['datefield'][ii].value;

                pFrm[sName].value = pFrm['date_dd_' + sName].value + '/' + pFrm['date_mm_' + sName].value + '/' + pFrm['date_yyyy_' + sName].value;
            }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the fnPreSubmit() js function?

Comment: "onsubmit="return fnPreSubmit()" in the form suggests that when form was submitted or Apply now button was clicked "fnPreSubmit()" function was called. Find this function in your code and action might be getting set there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form attribute `action` can be blank (it means the form data will be submitted to the same page) or another page (the submitted data will be processed in that page).

As you can see the form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

The `enctype` attribute specifies how the form-data will be encoded when submitting it to the server.

The `enctype` attribute can be used only with `method="post"`.

**multipart/form-data**

No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

```
<input type="file">
```

Finally the form submit is triggered by a javascript function `fnPreSubmit` delegate to some check and to the form submit.

Answer (score 4):

The value on the action maybe blank, but as you can see the *form* tag have an *onsubmit* attribute which will trigger once you click the button. To check what the form is doing upon clicking the button you can refer to the javascript function specified on the *onsubmit* attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the form is actually submitted by some Javascript code. The line `onsubmit="return fnPreSubmit()"` binds a call to the fnPreSubmit-function to the submit-event. Take a look at that function, you'll likely find the url where the form get's submitted to there.

Update: In the JS code you posted, an `'ActionSubmit'`-event gets pushed to `dataLayer`. Follow the trace further there, the events will have to be processed somewhere.